# Orthogonal Projection of $ z $ onto the Affine set $ \left\{ x \mid A x = b \right\} $

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, inner-products, least-squares

Suppose $A$ is **fat**(number of columns > number of rows) and **full row rank**. The projection of $z$ onto $\{x\mid Ax = b\}$ is (affine)

> $$P(z) = z - A^T(AA^T)^{-1}(Az-b)$$

**How to show this?**

Note:  $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ is the pseudo-inverse of $A$

What I am thinking is from:

1. Least square problem:  $$\text{min $\left\|\: Ax-b \,\right\|_2$}$$
   The solution for this is $\hat{x} = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$. It seems $(Az - b )$ above is the role of $b$ here.
2. Vector projection of $x$ onto $y$:    $$p = \frac{x^Ty}{y^Ty}y$$

But I still cannot figure out how to prove the above result.

Comment: Can you recall what mean "fat" and "full raw rank" for matrices. Not easy to find the definitions on the Internet.

Comment: fat here means number of column > number of row. full row rank means $A$'s all rows are linearly independent.

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318637/27978

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The projection of $z$ onto the set $\{x:\  Ax=b\}$ is given by the solution of
$$
\min \frac12\|x-z\|^2 \quad \text{ subject to } Ax=b.
$$
The KKT system is a necessary (since constraints are linear) and sufficient (since this is a convex problem):
$$
Ax=b, \quad x-z +A^T\lambda = 0.
$$
Multiply the second equation by $A$, solve for $\lambda$: $\lambda=(AA^T)^{-1}(Az-b)$, plug this again into the second equation to obtain
$$
x = z - A^T\lambda =z-A^T (AA^T)^{-1}(Az-b)
$$

Comment: How to get $x - z + A^T\lambda$? Do you form the Lagrangian and take the gradient of Lagrangian with respect to $x$ and get $x - z + A^T\lambda$?

Comment: Exactly, the Lagrangian is $\frac12\|x-z\|^2 + \lambda^T(Ax-b)$.

Comment: This also follows from linear algebra, since at the optimum, you have $x-z \bot \ker A$.

Comment: @daw Additional question, you solve $x-z+A^T\lambda=0$ for $\lambda$ instead of $x$ and at last you can find $x$ why? Because of KKT? primal optimal = dual optimal?  I am a little bit confused about this. thx!

Comment: I use the equation twice: first to get $\lambda$ (while applying $Ax=b$), second to get $x$.