# Solve Quadratic Programming Problem with Linear Underdetermined Equality Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have an underdetermined system of equations $ C x = d $ (to be solved for $ x $). I want to find $ x $ such that it makes $ {x}^{T} B x $ minimum. What options do I have to solve this?

$ B $ and $ C $ are sparse matrices, but they can have arbitrary spectrums. If this makes it complicated, assume the simplest case (for example positive-definiteness of $ B $).

The problem can be written as:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & {x}^{T} B x \\
\text{subject to} \quad & C x = d
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Do you mean $ \arg \min_{x} {x}^{T} B x \; \text{subject to} \; A x = b $?

Comment: No, it is actually the other way around. The problem is a constrained underdetermined system of equations.

Comment: It is exactly what Royi said. The solution method for the positive semidefinite case can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Equality_constraints).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is given by:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & {x}^{T} B x \\
\text{subject to} \quad & C x = d
\end{align*}$$

Where $ B $ is [Positive Semi Definite (PSD) matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix).

Since $ B $ is PSD one could write the problem as:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min \quad & {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & C x = d
\end{align*}$$

Where $ {A}^{T} A = B $ (Since it is PSD it is guaranteed such $ A $ exists) and $ b = \boldsymbol{0} $.

Now, this a simple [Least Squares problem with Linear Equality Constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724697).

The Lagrangian is given by:

$$ L \left( x, \nu \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + {\nu}^{T} \left( C x - d \right) $$

From KKT Conditions the optimal values of $ \hat{x}, \hat{\nu} $ obeys:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
{A}^{T} A & {C}^{T} \\ 
C & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x} \\ 
\hat{\nu}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
{A}^{T} b \\ 
d
\end{bmatrix} $$

Since $ B = {A}^{T} A $ and $ b = \boldsymbol{0} $ the above reduces to:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
B & {C}^{T} \\ 
C & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x} \\ 
\hat{\nu}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{0} \\ 
d
\end{bmatrix} $$

Now all needed is to solve the above with any Linear System Solver.
If you want to use iterative procedure you may use [Linear Least Squares with Linear Equality Constraints - Iterative Solver](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2422044/33) (With included MATLAB Code).

Comment: No need to use the least squares solution, see the link in my other comment.

Comment: @LinAlg, You can see that they converge to the same exact solution :-).