# Projection on convex sets with equality and inequality constraints

Tags: convex-analysis, projection

I want to find the projection of a vector called "a" on a closed and convex set with linear constraints. The set is in the following form:
\begin{array}{ll}
& Ax = b \\
& Bx \le d \\
&x \ge 0.
\end{array}
I know I need to solve the following problem to get the projection:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}  & || x-a||^2 \\
& Ax = b \\
& Bx \le d \\
&x \ge 0.
\end{array}
However, I am looking for an efficient way (instead of solving with commercial software like CPLEX) using the structure, convexity, and linearity of the set. I was wondering if anyone knows how to find the projection on this type of feasible region and space properties efficiently. Any resource that has addressed this issue will also help a lot. 
Note that I found this "[Projection of $z$ onto the affine set $\{x\mid Ax = b\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320363/projection-of-z-onto-the-affine-set-x-mid-ax-b?newreg=7a5355100daf440d9d8e5fe57bbf63f8)" here, but the KKT condition requires other conditions in my problem that lead to non-linear constraints. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could use any quadratic program (QP) solver. For example, SQOPT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. CPLEX can solve quadratic objectives with the set of constraints, and I get the optimal solutions, but I am looking for efficient ways to solve this problem using mathematical properties like getting the solution by multiplying some matrices and doing similar things instead of optimizing using commercial software.