# Projection of $ z $ onto the Affine Half Space $ \left\{ x \mid A x = b, \; x \geq 0 \right\} $

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, inner-products, least-squares

This is exactly the same question as [Orthogonal Projection of $ z $ onto the Affine set $ \left\{ x \mid A x = b \right\} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320363/projection-of-z-onto-the-affine-set-x-mid-ax-b) except I want to project on only a half affine space instead of a full affine space.

The parameters $A$ and $b$ of the problem are as in the linked question : from this question we know that a projection of $z$ onto the affine subspace $\{x\mid Ax=b\}$ is given by :

$$x =z-A^T (AA^T)^{-1}(Az-b)$$

( we suppose here that $A$ has more columns than rows and is full rank, as in the quoted question).

1. What about the projection onto the half-space ?
2. What if I want the projections of $z$ onto the affine half-space or the full affine space, but regarding another scalar product than the canonical one, say the one related to a bilinear symmetric definite positive endomorphism given by a matrix $P$.

Comment: I haven't tried to derive a closed form. But this is intersection of sets which the projection to each is known. So just use the method in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492095.

Comment: I would express your problem as a convex optimization problem and just solve it using a suitable optimization algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is given by:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - z \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & A x = b \\
& x \geq 0
\end{aligned}$$

I am not sure there is a closed form solution for this.
Moreover, since the set $ \left\{ x \mid x \geq 0 \right\} $ isn't a sub space we can't use the alternating projection method (See [Projections onto Convex Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projections_onto_convex_sets)).

It can be solved using the [Dykstra's Projection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dykstra%27s_projection_algorithm) from [Orthogonal Projection onto the Intersection of Convex Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492095).

The projection onto each set are given by:

1. $ \operatorname{Proj}_{ \left\{ x \mid A x = b \right\} } \left( z \right) = z - {A}^{T} {\left( A {A}^{T} \right)}^{-1} \left( A z - b \right) $.
2. $ \operatorname{Proj}_{ \left\{ x \mid x \geq 0 \right\} } \left( z \right) = \max \left( z, 0 \right) $.

A MATLAB implementation of the projection using [Dykstra's Projection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dykstra%27s_projection_algorithm) which is verified vs. CVX is available at my [StackExchange Mathematics Q3537129 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes).