# Solve Linear Least Squares with $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Regularization with Linear Equality and Non Negativity Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, least-squares, numerical-optimization

I'm searching for a way to solve the following problem in MATLAB.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|Ax-b\|_2 + \lambda \|Cx\|_1\\ \text{subject to} & D x = 0\\ & -x \leq 0\end{array}$$

In MATLAB, `lsqlin` doesn't take the $\ell_1$ regularization into account, and [`l1_ls`](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/l1_ls) is only considering the constraint $x \geq 0$. Is there a way to solve the problem in MATLAB?

Comment: You can solve this problem using primal-dual methods, i.e. chambolle-pock.

Comment: I think that the verb "minimize" is lacking; besides, can you give some details about your matrices $A,C,D$ ?  Sizes, being sparse or not...

Comment: @TSF Thanks for the very interesting reference to Chambolle-Pock (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01346507/document)

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify a little your problem setting. Do you agree ?

Comment: ... in particular placing the $2$ and the $1$ as **indices** instead of **exponents**. But maybe, one has to add an exponent $2$ to $AX+B$ ? Please answer.

Comment: Why not use [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx)?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo. Thanks. I will try to use CVX lib.

Comment: Thanks for the editing.

Comment: Why not considering the minimization of $\|Ax-b\|_2 + \lambda \|Cx\|_1+\mu \|D x\|_2$ ?

Comment: @Jean Marie, I think, it is somewhat different. But, similary, I tried to solve it using Lagrangian and dual function, but it is so complicated because I am not goot at optimization.

Comment: @geun-younglee The beauty of CVX is that you don't need to be good at optimization to be a healthy consumer of numerical optimization algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is given by:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| C x \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & D x = 0 \\
& x \geq 0
\end{aligned}$$

Probably the fastest solver to this kind of a problem is by some adaptation of the ADMM algorithm.

Yet, a simple solver can be done by the Projected Sub Gradient Method.
In this case we need a projection onto the convex set $ \mathcal{D} = \left\{ x \mid D x = 0, x \geq 0 \right\} $. Since the set $ \left\{ x \mid x \geq 0 \right\} $ isn't a sub space we can't use the alternating projection method (See [Projections onto Convex Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projections_onto_convex_sets)). So we'll use the [Dykstra's Projection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dykstra%27s_projection_algorithm) from [Orthogonal Projection onto the Intersection of Convex Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492095).

The projection onto each set are given by (You may have a look at [Projection of $ z $ onto the Affine Half Space $ \left\{ x \mid A x = b, \; x \geq 0 \right\} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537129)):

1. $ \operatorname{Proj}_{ \left\{ x \mid D x = 0 \right\} } \left( y \right) = y - {D}^{T} {\left( D {D}^{T} \right)}^{-1} \left( D y \right) $.
2. $ \operatorname{Proj}_{ \left\{ x \mid x \geq 0 \right\} } \left( y \right) = \max \left( y, 0 \right) $.

The Sub Gradient of the objective function is given by $ {A}^{T} \left( A x - b \right) + \lambda {C}^{T} \operatorname{sign} \left( D x \right) $.

Throw all of this into a simple iterative Sub Gradient and you have a solver.
The MATLAB code is available at my [StackExchange Mathematics Q3892375 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes).

P. S.

By generating all matrices randomly the solution is usually given by the zero vector.