# Closed form solution for least squares with linear constraints problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

I'm trying to figure out if the following linear program has a closed form solution

$$ 
\begin{align}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} ||x&-\alpha||^2 \\
Ax &= b \\
x &\geq 0
\end{align}
$$
where $\alpha$ is a constant vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix with real coefficients, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Any hint on how to figure this out is also welcome.

Edit:
The Lagrangian is
$$
||x-\alpha ||_2^2 -\lambda x+\mu(Ax-b)
$$
and the KKT conditions are
$$
2(x-\alpha) - \lambda \mathbf{1} + \sum_i \mu_i A_i = 0 \\
\lambda \cdot x = 0 \\
x \geq 0 \\
A_i x - b_i = 0 \quad \forall i \\
\lambda \geq 0
$$
where $A_i$ is the $i$th line of matrix $A$.

Comment: Have you tried to write down the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions)?

Comment: I tried to look them up and write them down for my case. I hope it's correct, first time I do this. What does this tell me? @dvdgrgrtt

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537129/projection-of-z-onto-the-affine-half-space-left-x-mid-a-x-b-x-g

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the answer there says he didn't know whether there is a closed form solution - thought the link was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether your problem has a closed form solution (it'll probably depend on $A$, $b$, $\alpha$), but let's try to work it out.

To start with, we need to fix the KKT's - yours are not correct. Note that the condition $x\ge 0$ is a shortcut for $x_i \ge 0$ for all $i$. Then, the Lagrangian is
$$
L(x,\lambda,\mu) = \lVert x-\alpha\rVert^2 - 2\lambda^T x + 2\mu^T(Ax-b)
$$
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^m$ (we use $2\lambda$ and $2\mu$ because it'll be useful in a moment). Now we can write the KKT's:
\begin{align}
2(x-\alpha) - 2\lambda + 2A^T\mu &= 0 \tag{1}\label{1}\\
x &\ge 0  \tag{2}\label{2}\\
Ax - b &= 0  \tag{3}\label{3}\\
\lambda &\ge 0  \tag{4}\label{4}\\
\lambda_i x_i &= 0 \qquad \forall i=1,\dots,n.  \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{align}

From (\ref{1}), we get
$$
x=\alpha+\lambda-A^T\mu
$$
(see how the 2's simplify).

From now on, we'll assume $m<n$ and $A$ full row rank. Indeed, if $m \ge n$, your problem has either a single solution or no solutions depending on whether $b$ is in the column space of $A$ or not, respectively.
Injecting the expression for $x$ into the primal feasibility condition (\ref{3}), we get
\begin{align}
A(\alpha+\lambda-A^T\mu) = b &\implies \mu = (AA^T)^{-1}(A\alpha + A\lambda - b) \\
&\implies x=\alpha+\lambda-A^T(AA^T)^{-1}(A\alpha + A\lambda - b)
\end{align}
or equivalently
$$
x_i = \alpha_i+\lambda_i-A_i^T(AA^T)^{-1}(A\alpha + A\lambda - b)
$$
for all $i$ and where $A_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$ - we can take the inverse of $AA^T$ because of the assumptions we made on A.

At this point, one would use the fact that (\ref{5}) implies that at least one between $x_i$ and $\lambda_i$ must be equal to zero and try to come up with the solution. Unfortunately, in our case, the term $A\lambda$ couples all the variables together and the problem is not trivial (the case $n=2$ and $m=1$ should be doable, but it'll take you some time).

To conclude, the KKT method doesn't seem to yield a closed form solution. But maybe there are other, better approaches (I couldn't come up with any, though). I hope this was helpful, anyway.

Comment: Yes, thank you.